# Default compiler for packages downloaded using apt or yum

Tags: linux, gcc, boost, clang

I'm curious to know which compiler is used by default to build libraries installed using the Linux utilities apt or yum.

This is important because if those libraries are compiled with gcc, there may be compatibility issues when using clang to write a simple program, particularly if the compiler flags differ.

To mitigate any potential risks, should I consider building all my dependencies from source or it'ssafe to use libraries built using gcc and the main program is compiled with clang?

Comment: It is safe. Which compiler was used depends on the distribution, but normally I would expect `gcc` and `g++` (not suffixed with version).

Comment: On debian-likes just use `apt install build-essential`. You can also just build the whole show `apt install build-dep XYZ; apt source --compile XYZ` and you get the entire thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single answer to this question as each distribution might have its own policies.  Generally, gcc is more common, mainly because most distributions got started before clang was around.

However, it isn't as important as you think.  Linux has a standard [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for each architecture that it supports, which specifies things like calling conventions, argument passing, memory layout of structs, and so on.  For example, on x86-64 it uses the [x86-64 SysV ABI](https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI).  Both gcc and clang will by default produce code that conforms to the ABI, and so they will interoperate correctly, even if your library is compiled with one and your libraries with another.  Most common options for debugging and optimization (`-g*`, `-O*`, most `-f` optimization options, etc) will maintain ABI compatibility so you (and library packagers) can safely use those too.

The compilers do have certain special options that are incompatible with the ABI (e.g. `-fpack-struct`, `-mregparm`), but the documentation for those options should have explicit warnings about the incompatibility.  Unless you are using some very oddball distribution, you can safely assume that your system's libraries were built without using any of these options, and so if you don't use any of them either, you don't have to worry about compiler choice.